# Resource allocation of jre - details in a file using JMX

Tags: java, jmx

For our project, we need to obtain the various resource allocation details in a text file using `JMX`. We have studied the JMX tutorial but we still are having difficulties understanding the same. If someone can explain, it would be of great help.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: We created an MBean for java class and watched its performance on jconsole which graphically showed memory usage, heap, memory, thread count etc. For our project we need this information in a log file. is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[JMX](http://www.slideshare.net/zeroproductionincidents/jmx-introduction-16593365) provides various MBeans that allow you to monitor the current state of the jvm including various metrics like cpu usage, heap & non-heap usage, GC utilization, thread count etc.

[JMXTrans](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/wiki) is a nice project that allows you to query these metrics and write to different backends include log files (It has a write for Log4j).
[It](https://github.com/jmxtrans) has an embedded jar version and a jvm agent version too.